# Error using locq2 from REAT package, "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r

I am using the `locq2` function from the [`REAT`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/REAT/index.html) package in R. I have tried to follow the [package documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/REAT/versions/3.0.2/topics/locq2) on how to use `locq2`.

The difference is that I am using my own dataset. Here is my code:

```
lqs <- locq2(e_ij = data2$emp_all,
             data2$ind_code,
             data2$region_code,
             LQ.output = "df")
```

When I execute my code, I get the [following error][1]:

> Error in locqs[, i] <- locq(locq_workfile_j$e_ij,
> sum(locq_workfile_j$e_ij), : number of items to replace is not a
> multiple of replacement length

Below you find my data. Any assistance on this issue will be of great help

```
data2<-data_locq2  #See trible below of data2 contents
  datapasta::tribble_paste(data2)
  tibble::tribble(
~ind_code, ~region_code, ~emp_all,
   "1151",         "40",      9.5,
   "2111",         "40",    374.5,
   "2123",         "40",     59.5,
   "2131",         "40",      534,
   "2211",         "40",    374.5,
   "2212",         "40",     59.5,
   "2213",         "40",      9.5,
   "2331",         "40",     59.5,
   "2332",         "40",    174.5,
   "4461",         "80",     5344,
   "4471",         "80",     2014,
   "4481",         "80",     2132,
   "4482",         "80",      486,
   "4483",         "80",      385,
   "4511",         "80",     1072,
   "4512",         "80",      487,
   "4521",         "80",   3749.5,
   "4529",         "80",   1749.5,
   "4531",         "80",      357,
   "4532",         "80",      883,
   "4533",         "80",      361,
   "4539",         "80",      639,
   "4541",         "80",     1399,
   "4542",         "80",    374.5,
   "4543",         "80",    374.5,
   "4811",         "80",     59.5,
   "4812",         "80",     59.5,
   "4831",         "80",    174.5,
   "4832",         "80",      9.5,
   "4841",         "80",     4158
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your data doesn't work is because it is not fully complete with data for all industries in all regions. Consider their example data:

```
data(G.regions.industries)
sapply(split(G.regions.industries,G.regions.industries$region_code),nrow)
BB BE BW BY HB HE HH MV NI NW RP SH SL SN ST TH 
17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17
```

And your data:

```
sapply(split(data2,data2$region_code),nrow)
40 80 
 9 21
```

One approach is to use the `complete` function from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
 complete_data <- complete(data2,
                           region_code, ind_code,
                           fill = list(emp_all = 0))
complete_data
## A tibble: 60 x 3
#   region_code ind_code emp_all
#   <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 40          1151         9.5
# 2 40          2111       374. 
# 3 40          2123        59.5
# 4 40          2131       534  
# 5 40          2211       374. 
# 6 40          2212        59.5
# 7 40          2213         9.5
# 8 40          2331        59.5
# 9 40          2332       174. 
#10 40          4461         0  
## … with 50 more rows
```

Now the `locq2` function will work:

```
locq2(e_ij = complete_data$emp_all,
      complete_data$ind_code,
      complete_data$region_code,
      LQ.output = "df")
#Location quotients 
#I = 30 industries, J = 2 regions 
#
#   j_region i_industry        LQ
#1        40       1151 16.871903
#2        40       2111 16.871903
#3        40       2123 16.871903
#4        40       2131 16.871903
#5        40       2211 16.871903
#... and 25 more rows.
```